# How to change the order of bar charts in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a bar chart of `total count` (y-axis) vs `day of the month` (x-axis).

The below shown snippet of code sorts the `total count`, in descending order from left to right, as seen in the image below:

Python is automatically sorting the chart to show the largest sized bar on the left and the smallest sized bar on right, as shown below:

[image]

What I would really like the code to do is to sort the `day of the month` in ascending order instead of sorting on `total count`.

May I get some hints on how to go about this?

Here is the piece of code I am using for this:

```
for g, sub_df in May_DATA.groupby('Plaza_Id'):
    sub_df['Date'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
    plt.title(g)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Is your date column a datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that the column `May_DATA['Data']` are datetimes (you can check the datatypes of your columns using `df.info`), you can sort that column by dates before your plotting loop. Something like:

```
for g, sub_df in May_DATA.sort('Date').groupby('Plaza_Id'):
    sub_df['Date'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
    plt.title(g)
    plt.show()
```

If the column `May_DATA['Date']` is not a datetime, you'll need to first change it to datetime using `May_DATA['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(May_DATA.Date)`.